# Unable to execute the command rasa run actions

Tags: module, rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-sdk

I am using python 3.10.11 and rasa 3.6.0
After editing actions.py file by adding custom action code when I try to execute rasa run actions
I am getting an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasa_sdk_plugins'

Hence the code isn't getting built properly and even though rasa train runs successfully, it is not giving the proper output.

I tried executing pip install rasa[full] and also pip install rasa-sdk. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to downgrade your rasa. `pip3 uninstall rasa && pip3 install rasa==3.5.0`